# Switching between multiple display record formats on enter press

Tags: c, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I've recently discovered abscense of thing like ILE C source for reading and writing physical file through multi-recorded display file, so trying to create one myself.

Sources for input are [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161023040720/http://www.marce.com:80/ejemplos_aplicaciones_c.html) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161023040720/http://www.marce.com:80/ejemplos_aplicaciones_c.html)

So, there is possibility to do it with RPG and certain indicators.

It looks like:

```
C                   Exfmt     Screen
C                   If        *In25 = *Off
C                     ...enter key pressed
C                   Else
C                     ...function key pressed
C                   EndIf
```

where we've

```
d  Cmd_Enter      c                   Const(x'F1')
```

[Source](https://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200509/msg00005.html)

However, when I try to do exactly same thing with C compilation fails.

Here is the part of sample:

```
#define ENTER   0xF1;
```

...

```
_SYSindara indicator_area;
do
{ 
    if(somevar != NULL)
    {

    indicator_area[ENTER] == IND_OFF;

    //do stuff

    if (indicator_area[EXIT] == IND_ON)
    {
        break;
     }
}
while(indicator_area[ENTER] != IND_ON);
```

Errors I'm getting on every line that contains `ENTER`:

`MYLIB/PGMSRC(SRC), 113.27: CZM0275(30) Unexpected text ';' encountered.`

I've tried to define `ENTER` as `0xD` (enter ASCII code), `0xF1`, `24` (*in25 like in source above) - nothing helps get this code to work.

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: I assume the location of the error points to a place where `ENTER` is used. Whenever you have problems with macros, you should take a look at preprocessor result. In your case you will end up with something like `indicator_area[0xF1;]` which is invalid syntax.

Comment: BTW: `indicator_area[ENTER] == IND_OFF;` This is no assignment. Your compiler should issue some warning (as soon as it is able to compile without errors.) about unused result of expression or something similar.

Comment: @Gerhardh nice gotcha's. Haven't touched c for a while and this is a result. Such a shame thou.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your confusion is that you are trying to use the ENTER value for the AID byte `x'F1'` to index into the `indicator_area` that you defined with

```
_SYSindara indicator_area;
```

This won't work as `_SYSindara` is defined as `char[99]`. You can retrieve the indicator area from the display file into there, but you will not see the AID byte which resides in the Display file I/O Feedback Area. That is retrieved using

```
#include <xxfdbk.h>

_XXIOFB_T *iofb;          /* Pointer to the file's feedback area */
_XXIOFB_DSP_ICF_T *dspfb; /* Pointer to display file specific feedback area */

iofb = _Riofbk ( fp );
dspfb = iofb + iofb->file_dep_fb_offset;

if (dspfb->AID_byte_indic == ENTER) {
  // do something
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/hriofbk.htm#hriofbk) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/dm/rbal3fedbk.htm) in the IBM Knowledge Center for IBM i. And in `QSYSINC/H(XXFDBK.C)` on your `IBM i`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from the #define like below:

```
#define ENTER   0xF1
```

It's one of the quirks of C syntax that compiler definitions shouldn't have an ending semicolon (unless you need it for a multi-statement define but that is beyond the need for this question).

Longer explanation:
Compiler definitions (#define) are in reality simple text replacements in your source code prior to compilation.  What is occurring on the following line

```
indicator_area[ENTER] = IND_OFF;
```

is that it gets substituted as
    indicator_area[0xF1;] = IND_OFF;
which is a syntax error.  For compiler definitions, semicolons are not a special end of statement character like it is for regular C statements.  If you need to do a multi-line compiler definition (which you probably don't), you should escape the new line to do so.  For example:

```
#define MY_LONG_DEFINE This is a test \
     This is only a test.  If this had \
     been longer, more lines would be \
     escaped.
```

I should also note that @Gerhardh is correct in that you should not be using double equals for assignment.  I have corrected it in the example above.